# Composite primary keys vs auto increment primary key in sql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I need the advice of someone who has a greeter experience.

I have an associative entity in my database, like that:

```
Table2-> CustomerID, ServiceID, DateSub
```

Since the same customer (with PK, for example 1111) can require the same service (with PK, for example 3) more than once **but never in the same date** , the composite PK of Table 2 can't be just (CustomerID, ServiceID).

Now I have 2 options:

1- Also **"DateSub" will be a primary key**, so the PK of table 2 will be (CustomerID, ServiceID, DateSub)

2- Create a **specific PK** for the associative entity (for example, Table2ID, and so CustomerID and Service ID will be FK)

Which of the 2 approach would you follow and why? Thank you

Comment: 2nd options is always better!. Cuz date should never be Primary Key. Ton of customers do the same service on the same day. So you need a specific PK for your table like 2nd option like you mentioned above ``Table2_id`` or just ``Id`` with Auto Increament checked

Comment: Maybe i would follow the first one

Comment: A primary key is a unique key so your second option would allow only 1 per cutomer irrespective of service..and do you anticipate that only one service request per day per customer.

Comment: I think that synthetic primary key is the best option - if it is needed at all. The uniqueness of `(CustomerID, ServiceID, DateI)` expression may be controlled by additional UNIQUE index if needed (but I doubt that it is useful).

Comment: PS. If you'll use composite PK nevertheless then think carefully for the most useful columns order in the index expression (it must improve the most part of queries to this table). Do not forget that PK is clustered index.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes I specified that there can be just one per day, so adding also Date as PK would guarantee the uniqueness of the combo (Customer ID - Service ID - Date )

Comment: Please change your "need an opinion" with "need advice"

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to decide whether is it your requirement to make combination of `CustomerID`, `ServiceID` amd `DateI` column as unique? If so then you should go for firt option.

Otherwise I would go for second option.

With first option if DateI is of date data type you will not be able to insert same service for a customer twice. If it's datetime then it's doable though.

If you want to use this primary key (composite primary key) in any other table as foreign key then you need to use all three columns there too.

Comment: I now added a clarification: The same customer can require the same service, but not more than once in the same date ( The service lasts one-3 months )

Comment: Is there any possibility to use this primary key as foreign key in any other table?

Comment: No, there's not

Comment: Then I would like to go to the first point. If uniqueness in those columns are not necessary then I would go for second option.

Comment: You can read the answer of Gordon Linoff in below link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043071/pros-cons-of-date-column-as-part-of-primary-key#:~:text=The%20primary%20key%20is%20composite,ID%20on%20the%20Parts%20Table.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to prefer the PK be "natural".  You have 3 columns that, together, can uniquely define each row.  I would consider using it.

The next question is what order to put the 3 columns in.  This depends on the common queries.  Please provide them.

An index (including the PK) is used only leftmost first.  It may be desirable to have some secondary key(s), for efficient access to other columns.  Again, let's see the queries.

If you have a lot of secondary indexes, it *may* be better to have a surrogate, `AUTO_INCREMENT` "id" as the PK.  Again, let's see the queries.

If you ever use a date range, then it is *probably* best to have `DateSub` last in any index.  (There are rare exceptions.)

How many rows in the table?

The table is `ENGINE=InnoDB`, correct?

Reminder:  The `PRIMARY KEY` is a Unique key, which is an `INDEX`.

`DateSub` is of datatype `DATE`, correct?